# Как гибко задавать критерии в функции поиска?

Tags: python, функции, dict

Есть небольшая функция которая возвращает нужный объект из словаря с указанными критериями, как можно модернизировать её так, чтобы можно было указывать критерии а-ля if 1 in list():
То-есть проверку есть ли элемент в нужном значении словаря в нашем случае список, ничего не приходит в голову, подскажите примеры.

```
def dict_parse(data, give_key=False, **keys):
    """Функция возвращает нужный объект из словаря с указанными критериями"""
    ki = keys.items()
    for i in data:
        dt = data[i]
        if all((dt[k] == v) for (k, v) in ki):
            if give_key:
                return i, dt
            return dt

    if give_key:
        return None, None

    return None
```

Comment: Передавать в функцию другую функцию, которая проверяет критерий?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как предложил [insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor):

```
def dict_find(data, predicate_fn, give_key=False):
    for k, v in data.items():
        if predicate_fn(k, v):
            if give_key:
                return k, v
            return v

    if give_key:
        return None, None

    return None
```

Теперь можно использовать с любым предикатом:

```
dict_find(data, lambda key, val: val['a'] == 'b')  # значение с элементом
dict_find(data, lambda key, _: key == 'by-key')    # значение по ключу
dict_find(data, lambda _, val: 1 in val)           # значение с единицей
```

Можно заготовить предикаты и связки:

```
def by_key(key):
   return lambda k, _: k == key

def in_list(val):
   return lambda _, v: isinstance(v, list) and val in v

def all_of(*predicates):
    return lambda k, v: all(p(k, v) for p in predicates)
```

И использовать:

```
d = {'a': 'b', 'b': [1, 2, 3]}

print(dict_find(d, by_key('a')))
print(dict_find(d, in_list(3)))
print(dict_find(d, all_of(by_key('b'), in_list(3))))
```

Comment: вроде бы это хорошее решение, но тогда пропадает возможность использовать несколько обязательных критериев, как я понял в вашем решении доступно лишь 1 предикт.

Comment: @HedgeHog напишите предикат, который проверяет несколько условий (через or или and), или например вызывает несколько заготовленных предикатов.